# I can't promote changes in drools workbench

Tags: drools, workbench, business-rules, kie, kie-workbench

I'm new in Drools Workbench.

As it is said in [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch18.html#wb.assetMgmtManagedRepositoryOperations), we can launch the "Promote changes process" by selecting the "Promote" button. This should create a task for the "kiemgmt" group, containing all the files that had been changed, to promote them via the UI.

But when I do so with a very simple project, nothing happen. I can't see the task, and the target branch isn't merged.

The console shows:

```
INFO  [AssetMgmt] (default task-49) Auto approve for user: myUser
INFO  [AssetMgmt] (default task-49) Operation : PromoteAsset
INFO  [AssetMgmt] (default task-49) Repository : MyRepository
INFO  [AssetMgmt] (default task-49) Project : null
INFO  [org.guvnor.asset.management.backend.handlers.AssetMgmtStartWorkItemHandler] (default task-49) Start asset management process: PromoteAssets
WARN  [org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog] (EJB default - 8) Variable content was trimmed as it was too long (more than 255 characters)
WARN  [org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog] (EJB default - 8) Variable content was trimmed as it was too long (more than 255 characters)
WARN  [org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog] (EJB default - 8) Variable content was trimmed as it was too long (more than 255 characters)
WARN  [org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog] (EJB default - 8) Variable content was trimmed as it was too long (more than 255 characters)
WARN  [org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog] (EJB default - 8) Variable content was trimmed as it was too long (more than 255 characters)
WARN  [org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog] (EJB default - 8) Variable content was trimmed as it was too long (more than 255 characters)
WARN  [org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog] (EJB default - 8) Variable content was trimmed as it was too long (more than 255 characters)
WARN  [org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog] (EJB default - 8) Variable content was trimmed as it was too long (more than 255 characters)
WARN  [org.jbpm.services.task.audit.impl.model.TaskVariableImpl] (EJB default - 8) Task variable 'in_commits_per_file' content was trimmed as it was too long (more than 4000 characters)
```

I'm using Drools 6.5.0

Comment: I see the same problem with 6.4.0.  Did you resolve the problem?

Comment: I received this answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-usage/2KIIqESZNZ0

We keep waiting...